# Where did clans go from Diablo 3 RoS?

Tags: diablo-iii

Currently I'm in a clan in Diablo 3 RoS, but now I would like to create my own clan.

So I looked for information on the internet and found an article ["Reaper of Souls™ First Look: Clans and Communities"](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/12891941/reaper-of-souls%E2%84%A2-first-look-clans-and-communities-2-19-2014), that describes process, but for some reason I can't repeat it. I'm able to create communities but no clans.

Was this option removed or something changed in a process described?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a clan if you are currently in one. You can only belong to one clan at a time. In order to create a new one you will have to leave your current clan.